# Sending user info through link in email to cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I am trying to re-direct the receiver of an email to their preference center.

This is the link:

```ampscript
<a alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="other" href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat(CloudPagesURL(26816),'&'))=%%" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">
<span style="font-size:12px;">
<span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<span style="color:#999999;">Preference Center</span> 
</span> </span> </a>
..
```

and this is how I am trying to receive the ContactID of the user in the Cloud Page:

```ampscript
@ID = %%ContactID%%
```

I get the following error message: "We couldn't open this page. Try again later."
What should I change in my code?

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors in your code, you probably haven't publish the cloud page yet. You need to press both Save and Publish

Comment: is there a reason you want to concat a &, why not just write `<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(26816)=%%">blah</a>`
And if you are using ContactID as subscriberkey, in landing page, you can just get the value from _subscriberkey: `set @contactID = _subscriberKey`

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343256/retrieve-parameters-from-the-url < this shows a good example of passing parameters in cloudpagesurl, and retrieving them in ampscript

Comment: @user131897 If you have more code you're not showing here, it could be a timeout message. If that's not the case, an old question looks pretty similar: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270573/error-on-redirecting-to-a-cloudpage